# Java calling Powershell script with function and not returning Write-Host to java

Tags: java, powershell

I am using Java to call powershell script. The powershell script is built with function and the function will write values to console. I need to capture those values in java.
my poweshell script is as below

```
 $TokenCSV="M:\work\Powershell\TokenExtractedFromDB_Spec.csv"
$TokenXlPath="M:\work\Powershell\TokenListconverted.xlsx"
$Switch="Token"
Write-Host "Inside ConvertCSVtoEXL2 calling fuc  :"
$x=ConverToExlFile $TokenCSV $TokenXlPath $Switch

###Function
function ConverToExlFile
{
 Param ([string]$TokenCSV,
        [string]$TokenXlPath,
        [string]$Switch)
    Write-Output "Inside ConverToExlFile Function  :"| Out-Null

    
    for($row = 2;$row -lt 10;$row++)
    {
    Write-Output "Inside for loop :$row"| Out-Null
    }
    return
}
```

while calling above code through java i m not getting values in while loop as given below. it just finishes once powershell script executes.

```
 Process proc = runtime.exec("cmd.exe /c powershell.exe  M:\\work\\Powershell\\V2\\ConvertCSVtoEXL2.ps1");
        System.out.println("2...");
        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        System.out.println("3");
       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
       {
            System.out.println(line);
            //System.out.println(reader.readLine());
            System.out.println("4");
       }
```

IT would be great if any one can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

- You don't need `cmd.exe`. You can directly run `powershell.exe`.
- Your *PowerShell* script is sending output to `Out-Null` so obviously nothing will be written to standard output.
- `powershell.exe` accepts a `-File` parameter which you can use to run your script.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class PrcBldTs {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("powershell.exe", "-File", "M:\\work\\Powershell\\V2\\ConvertCSVtoEXL2.ps1");
        Process p = pb.start();
        try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        }
        int exitStatus = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("exit status = " + exitStatus);
    }
}
```

Note that you must call method `waitFor()` so that your java code will wait until the *PowerShell* script terminates.

Remember that `ProcessBuilder` does **not** emulate a Windows command prompt. In the `ProcessBuilder` constructor you need to split the command that you pass into a list of words.

Of-course, if all you want to do is print the *PowerShell* script output, you can simply call method `redirectIO()` of class `ProcessBuilder`. Then the above code becomes:

```java
import java.io.IOException;

public class PrcBldTs {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("powershell.exe", "-File", "M:\\work\\Powershell\\V2\\ConvertCSVtoEXL2.ps1");
        pb.inheritIO();
        Process p = pb.start();
        int exitStatus = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("exit status = " + exitStatus);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `proc.waitFor();` before getting input stream from proc

Comment: `waitFor()` waits until the process terminates/finishes. If that process outputs something and that something is bigger than its internal buffer, then calling `waitFor()` without anything reading the `InputStream` will just deadlock.